# show/hide div using jquery with multiple independent divs

Tags: jquery

I have a series of multiple independent divs that need to be shown/hidden via a trigger. 
So far, the jquery code I have will show the div clicked, but the hide part wont work.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(".show_options_div").click(function() { 
  $(this).next(".toggleOptions").slideToggle("normal");         
  $(this).slideToggle("fast");  
});

$(".hide_options_div").click(function() {
  $(this).prev(".toggleOptions").slideToggle("normal");         
  $(this).prev(".show_options_div").slideToggle("fast");    
});
```

here is the HTML:

```
<a class="show_options_div" style="display:block;">
    <div class="drop_down_arrow"></div>
</a>

<div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">    
  <a class="hide_options_div">
    <div class="drop_up_arrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>

<a class="show_options_div" style="display:block;">
    <div class="drop_down_arrow"></div>
</a>

<div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
  <a class="hide_options_div">
    <div class="drop_up_arrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>


<a class="show_options_div" style="display:block;">
    <div class="drop_down_arrow"></div>
</a>

<div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
  <a class="hide_options_div">
    <div class="drop_up_arrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your hide function

```
$(this).prev(".show_options_div").slideToggle("fast");
```

the prev method only finds the immediate previous element, since this is not .show_options_div, this is not finding anything

.show_options_div is the prev element of .toggleOptions so changing to

```
$(this).parent(".toggleOptions").prev(".show_options_div").slideToggle("fast");
```

and the

```
$(this).prev(".toggleOptions").slideToggle("normal");
```

should be changed to

```
$(this).parent(".toggleOptions").slideToggle("normal");
```

for reference

[jQuery prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)